# Is there mathematical value in zero dimensional matrices or 1-element arrays?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I always thought as 2-dimensional matrices as functions $f: N \times M \to \mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is some field, and $N, M$ are, by abuse of notation (or maybe can be thought of as ordinals I believe) $N = {0, 1, 2, \ldots, N - 1}$, and $M = {0, 1, 2, \ldots, M - 1}$. Note that I start indexing with zero, this is just due to my CS background, but it should be equivalent to start indexing with 1. Also note that I'm not necessarily thinking about linear transformations here, just "squares" of numbers.

In a similar fashion it is easy to define k-dimensional matrices $f: \prod_k N_k \to \mathbb{K}$.

Taking this idea further we have that $f: 1 \to \mathbb{K}$ and $f: \varnothing \to \mathbb{K}$, and also $f: 1 \times 1 \times 1 \ldots \to \mathbb{K}$.

This would all be some variation of an array of a single number.

My question is twofold: (1) Is this idea correct or am I going wrong somewhere? (2) Is there any mathematical value to considering these last objects that are essentially just "arrays of one number" (what I mean roughly is, are there examples of cases where these distinctions become important, maybe in category theory or something like that?), or am I better of just thinking about them as "isomorphic with the field" and calling it a day? I believe for my last example the set of all the functions of the form $f: \varnothing \to \mathbb{K}$ can probably be written as $\{(\varnothing, \mathbb{K}, \varnothing)\}$.

I know these objects exist, at least in some form, in some programming languages, and things like "singletons" do make sense and are similar in a way.

I'm not sure what to tag this question with, it is kind of a pedantic detail but I've been curious about this for some time.

Comment: The way I would answer your title question is that it allows for the mathematical development of linear algebra in a manner which is expressed independent of the dimension, without requiring special treatment of edge cases (such as dimension $1$).

Comment: For example, a linear transformation from a $k$ dimensional space to an $m$ dimensional space is represented using a $k$-by-$m$ matrix, *even if* one or both of $k$ or $m$ is equal to $1$ or to $0$.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.